# In Application Compiling - Java

Tags: java

I'm writing an application where there is a text editor for the user to write his or her own code. I then want to compile said code, which is easy enough. The trick I don't know how to do is call a function in the applications source from the users compiled code

For example, if I have a class titled 'Player' with a function  MoveUp (); , how could I call that function from the users compiled code?

Comment: You can't call a method directly from a Java file. It would need a main method that called that method explicitly upon an instance of some `Player` object

Comment: @Benfir This smells like an XY problem. What do you want to originally achieve?

Comment: I'm making a game where users can learn programming by making an AI to interact with other players. They enter their code into a text editor in the game. Their code is similar to, check the distance from another player and then move to the player using functions I've pre-written. E.g. DistanceToPlayer (); or MoveTo ();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to compile the code already, and you know where the compiled class file is stored its actually not too bad. It just requires a bit of reflection.

```
    //replace filePath with the path to the folder where the class file is stored
    URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{filePath.toURI().toURL()});

    //this actually loads the class into java so you can use it
    Class<?> cs = Class.forName(compiledClassName, true, classLoader);

    //the getConstructor method will return the constructor based on the 
    //parameters that you pass in. The default constructor has none, but if 
    //you want a different constructor you just pass in the class of the 
    //object you want to use
    Constructor<?> ctor = cs.getConstructor();

    //you can then just create a new instance of your class
    Player player = (Player) ctor.newInstance();

    //You can then call any methods on the Player object that you want.
    player.MoveUp();
```

Remember that when you are compiling the code that the class package can move the location of the compiled class files. It may be easier to just remove the package statement of their code, or add package where you want it to go.

As a side note, if you are going to be doing this to multiple "Player" classes at the same time, each class will need a unique name for it. If they don't have that, they will end up sharing the same class file and all having the same code because of that.